# Redirect to parent after deleting an object with DeleteObject generic view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Let's say I have two models, Book and Page:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    pass

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

I need to delete a page and being redirected to the specific book that the page belonged to. To achieve this, I make a class based view to delete the page:

```
class PageDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Page

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('book_detail', self.book.pk)
```

The problem is that, since the object is deleted before get_success_url is called, this method fails, and I get a 404 error.

How could I do it?

**Update:**

Following the idea of @DrTyrsa, I have achieved it overriding the delete method, so the class would be as follows:

```
reverse_lazy = lambda name=None, *args : lazy(reverse, str)(name, args=args)

class PageDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Page

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('book_detail', self.book.pk)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.book_pk = self.get_object().book.pk
        return super(PageDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why does PageDeleteView have model = Book ? Shouldn't it be model = Page ?

Comment: You're right, jpic. I meant 'Page', so I have fixed it.

Comment: You don't need lazy reversing here, if you call `reverse` from a method this call is already "lazy" enough not to cause any problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save object's `pk` before deleting. In `__init__`, for example. And [name your URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use kwargs['pk'] ? (or maybe kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg])

Comment: DrTyrsa, my urls are named (not in the example), but in the url pattern I have the Page pk, but not the Book pk (should I?). It's the Book pk what I need in __init__ so maybe I should include it in the url pattern, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: @jantoniomartin I don't like it either, that's why I don't use class-based views. :-)

Comment: @jpic `self.kwargs` will have object's id, but not the related object's.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, I'm just beginning with them, and I find them quite convenient, but I still have to learn much.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, overriding the delete() method and saving the pk before deleting the object solves the problem. Thanks.